# Amcharts Export in IE

Tags: javascript, internet-explorer, amcharts

I have to export a chart into a blob string for a javascript pdf function.
I used this code :

```
var homeChartImg = "";
var tmp = new AmCharts.AmExport(chart);
tmp.init();
tmp.output({
    output: 'datastring',
    format: 'jpg'
},function(blob) {
    homeChartImg = blob;
});
```

It's work well BUT not in Internet Explorer.
I found this other way to make export : https://github.com/amcharts/export/
But I do't know how to use it in my case.

Comment: what version of IE were you using?

Comment: 10 & 11, with both there is a bug

Comment: You're using old version of amCharts export script. I strongly suggest switching to the new one: https://www.amcharts.com/tutorials/intro-exporting-charts/